# ユーザーページの信用度グラフの横軸ラベルに誤訳がある

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

ユーザー詳細ページからは信用度の時系列グラフを見ることができます。

ここの横軸には日付が書かれているのですが、「6月月」のように「月」が重なって表示されてしまっています。実際は「6月」のように表示されるべきです。

https://ja.traducir.win/ を見る限り似たような string はありません。もしかしたら「6月」という string と「月」という string が重なって表示されているのかもしれません。

システム側の問題と思われるので、修正できないでしょうか。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu?tab=reputation&StartDate=2021-07-09%2005:23:46Z&sort=graph

[image]

^ Here "June" is translated to "6月月", but it should be "6月".

Comment: 月名 (の短縮名) が個別に文字列が用意されているので、この辺りが怪しいですね。 https://ja.traducir.win/strings/8003 ロケールに合わせた表示を行う際、恐らく付け足される "月" と重複している可能性があります。

Comment: はい、それを疑っています。ただ、その場合もとの string が "Jun Month" みたく英語でもありえないものになるので、少し疑問はあるなあと思っています。英語版だと当然 "Month" はありませんでした。

Comment: ダメ元で "Jun" だけ "6" に設定してみます (rev 2022.6.10.42345)。次の反映で変わらなければ元に戻します。

Answer (score 5):

コメント欄で書いた通り、「月名の短縮表記」の翻訳 `Jun -> 6月`と、ロケールに合わせた日付フォーマット `XX 月 XX 日` とがバッティングしていたようです。

**確認のため "Jun" のみ "6" で翻訳を反映した結果:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ひとまず1月から12月までの文字列も翻訳を更新しておきました。

Comment: なるほど。調査ありがとうございます。こちら、月の名前の方ではなくて `XX 月` と「月」を付与した上で訳している https://ja.traducir.win/strings/5605 や https://ja.traducir.win/strings/2034 を変更した方が、月名の短縮表記が単独で使われたときも日などと複合して使われたときも両方対応できるのではないかと思いました。いかがでしょうか。